# Getting 96 MFCC features using python_speech_features

Tags: python, librosa

I want to train my model using 96 MFCC Features. I used Librosa and  I didnt get a promising result.
I then tried to use python_speech_features, however I can get no more than 26 features! why!
This is the shape for the same audio file

using `Librosa`

```
x = librosa.feature.mfcc(audio, rate, n_mfcc=96)
x.shape  # (96, 204)
```

using `python_speech_features`

```
mfcc_feature = pySpeech.mfcc(audio, rate, 0.025, 0.01, 96, nfft=1200, appendEnergy = True)
mfcc_feature.shape # output => (471, 26)
```

Any Thoughts!

Comment: Maybe you can checkout OpenSmile. It's pretty good to extract features from audio. Can generate 100+ features based on what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the implementations of `librosa` and `python_speech_features` differ from each other, structure-wise and even theory-wise. Based on the docs:

- https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.mfcc.html (also https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html)
- https://python-speech-features.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#python_speech_features.base.mfcc

You will notice that the outputs are different, `librosa mfcc output shape = (n_mels, t)` whereas `python_speech_features output = (num_frames, num_cep)`, so you need to transpose one of the two. Also you will notice that any `num_ceps` value above 26 in `python_speech_features` won't change a thing in the returned mfccs `num_ceps` that is because you are limited by the number of filters used. Therefore, you will have to increase that too. Moreover, you need to make sure that the [framing](https://superkogito.github.io/blog/SignalFraming.html) is using similar values (one is using samples count and the other durations) so you will have to fix that. Also `python_speech_features` accepts int16 values returned by scipy read function but librosa requires a float32, so you have to convert the read array or use `librosa.load()`. Here is a small snippet that includes the previous changes:

```
import librosa
import numpy as np
import python_speech_features
from scipy.io.wavfile import read


# init fname
fname = "sample.wav"

# read audio 
rate, audio = read(fname)

# using librosa 
lisbrosa_mfcc_feature = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio.astype(np.float32), 
                                             sr=rate,
                                             n_mfcc=96,
                                             n_fft=1024,
                                             win_length=int(0.025*rate),                                            
                                             hop_length=int(0.01*rate))
print(lisbrosa_mfcc_feature.T.shape)

# using python_speech_features
psf_mfcc_feature = python_speech_features.mfcc(signal=audio, 
                                               samplerate=rate, 
                                               winlen=0.025,
                                               winstep=0.01, 
                                               numcep=96,
                                               nfilt=96,
                                               nfft=1024, 
                                               appendEnergy=False)
print(psf_mfcc_feature.shape)


# check if size is the same
print(lisbrosa_mfcc_feature.shape == psf_mfcc_feature.shape)
```

I tested this and the output is the following:

```
(9003, 96)
(9001, 96)
False
```

It is not the exact same output but it just 2 frames difference.By the way the values won't be the same because each library is using a different approach to computing the MFCCs, `python_speech_features` uses [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) whereas librosa uses [short time Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform).